# django multiple select browser button in form like in html

Tags: python, html, django, forms

In html I can create a multiple select form like this :

```
<form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">{% csrf_token %}

<input type="file" name="image" multiple />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />

</form>
```

This gives me a browse button and I can select multiple files

How to create this form in django. I mean that can select multiple files

Here I want to save the each file in database with id. 
Is this the right way of doing ?
With this view its giving me error saying **init**() got unexpected arguement instance.

Comment: Look at these links: http://koensblog.eu/blog/7/multiple-file-upload-django/ and https://github.com/Chive/django-multiupload

Comment: @catavaran .. thank you that was useful.. But in multiple-file-upload-dajngo blog I wrote the code but it says unexpected key work arguement maximum_file_size

Comment: Hm.  Are you sure that you use `MultiFileField` in your form and not the `MultiFileInput`?

Comment: yeah I used MultiFileField

Comment: Then update your post with the code and stacktrace, please.

Comment: It says __init_-() got unexpected keyword arguement maximum_file_size

Comment: I have updated the code please have a look

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an error in the `__init__()` signature.  You wrote three underscore chars after the `init` instead of two.

Comment: can you look at my update... I am getting errors in my view. can you help ?

Comment: You should inherit your view from `FormView` instead of `CreateView`.